# Acumatica - Overriding Business logic, access protected methods

Tags: acumatica

I'm looking to override the InvoiceOrder logic of the SOInvoiceEntry graph in the business logic, so I can change the logic that aggregates invoices if the 'Bill Separately' option is not selected.

I've written an extension method below to replace the built in InvoiceOrder method.

```
public delegate void InvoiceOrderDelegate(DateTime invoiceDate, PXResult<SOOrderShipment, SOOrder, CurrencyInfo, SOAddress, SOContact, SOOrderType> order, PXResultset<SOShipLine, SOLine> details, Customer customer, DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice> list);

[PXOverride]
public virtual void InvoiceOrder(DateTime invoiceDate, PXResult<SOOrderShipment, SOOrder, CurrencyInfo, SOAddress, SOContact, SOOrderType> order, PXResultset<SOShipLine, SOLine> details, Customer customer, DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice> list, InvoiceOrderDelegate baseMethod)
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

I'm unsure how to access the original object's protected methods. Normally I'd just call `Base.DoSomething();`, but I presume I can't access protected methods as the extension object is not directly derived from SOInvoiceEntry.

Do I need to override the protected methods I want to use as well, or is there a way to access them from the extension?

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: Additional clarification:

Say I'm overriding the InvoiceOrder method. The tweak is small, so most of the code is copy pasted to the override method. Many lines invoke other methods of the SOInvoiceEntry graph. Any that are accessible can be called using `Base.Method()`. However, if an SOInvoiceEntry method is protected, it can't be called from the extension, as far as I can tell. 

e.g. Midway through the InvoiceOrder override method, I need to call `InvoiceCreated(newdoc, order);`, but this is protected. 

Do I need to override every method required by the InvoiceOrder method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the delegate you pass into the method as the base call. For InvoiceCreated you should be able to override it and call it as shown below:

```
public class SOInvoiceEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
{
    public delegate void InvoiceOrderDelegate(DateTime invoiceDate, 
        PXResult<SOOrderShipment, SOOrder, CurrencyInfo, SOAddress, SOContact, SOOrderType> order, 
        PXResultset<SOShipLine, SOLine> details, 
        Customer customer, 
        DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice> list);

    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void InvoiceOrder(DateTime invoiceDate, 
        PXResult<SOOrderShipment, SOOrder, CurrencyInfo, SOAddress, SOContact, SOOrderType> order, 
        PXResultset<SOShipLine, SOLine> details, 
        Customer customer, 
        DocumentList<ARInvoice, SOInvoice> list, 
        InvoiceOrderDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        //Code before
        baseMethod?.Invoke(invoiceDate, order, details, customer, list);
        //Code after

        // This also works, but the delegate should be used.
        //Base.InvoiceOrder(invoiceDate, order, details, customer, list);

        //InvoiceCreated(someInvoice, someSource);
    }

    [PXOverride]
    public  virtual void InvoiceCreated(ARInvoice invoice, SOOrder source, SOInvoiceEntry.InvoiceCreatedDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        baseMethod?.Invoke(invoice, source);
    }
}
```